# How to use cookies in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies, browser

I've got a problem, and I don't know if it's possible to solve, but i think it should be. Im working in Microsoft Visual C#, using a Windows Forms Application.

I don't know too much about websites. If a website stores a cookie on my computer, it will use that cookie to see if i'm logged in and with what account, right? So if I delete the cookies it will log me out. Or if I would add a certian cookie, the site will think I logged in. Am I right on this one?

So, for example, would it be possible to let my application store the cookie in a text file or something when I log in once, and then let it log in automaticly using that cookie?

And how would I do that?

Thank you in advance, it really is hard to find on google.

Comment: You can do it but it is arguably fundamentally wrong to mess with methods used by aonther company relating to authentication or authorisation.

Comment: @Lloyd, I disagree. If I wrote a non-browser application that looks in my browser cookie store for cookies to enable authentication when accessing resources on the site, then what'd be the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are specific to the web-browser. You certainly shouldn't be messing with cookie files.

If you mean you want to use the cookie to authenticate the win forms user, then one thing you *could* do is host a WebBrowser control and navigate to your login page, and then scrape a value that is only issued to logged in people. However this does not smell like a good design, and will only support IE (shdocvw, more specifically). Another option; ClickOnce supports fetcng a client "principal" via an asp.net web site, so you could use that for auth.

If you mean you want the winform to provide the cookie for an unrelated website... Don't do that :p

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work for the majority of websites or for all browsers. Browsers save their cookies in different places and some may even encrypt them considering the possibility of personal information in them. Most websites these days only save the session id in the cookie, the information specific to whether or not you are logged in is then stored in the session on the web server, and usually expires after so many minutes/hours. So if you did make an application that could remove and restore cookies, and assuming the cookie itself didn't expire, the server would get your session id from the cookie, see it's an expired session, create a new session for you, and force you to login again.